# Use other words for the same functionality of a reserved keyword in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, compilation

I'm exploring language interpreters and compilers to build a small international compiler that compiles JavaScript with little modifications (to the English reserved words), to vanilla JS.

**Modified JS Example:**

```
notfor(notlet i=0; i<5; i++) {
    ...
}
```

**obviously "notfor" and "notlet" will not be the real keywords*

**Vanilla JS Compilation:**

```
for(let i=0; i<5; i++) {
    ...
}
```

I've tried the RegEx approach, but I keep finding edge cases where the RegExes fail.

*Ex.* `/notfor(.*)/`, this fails when notfor(..){..} is put inside of a string or there is a closing parentheses in any part of the initialization, condition or final-expression of the for statement.

What is another simple approach to this problem?

Comment: I'd write a parser which separates string literals and template literals from actual code, and then use a regex to replace only the `notfor` etc in the actual code. It's doable - I've done it before - but it requires a good deal of code and effort. Most of the complication is due to the `${}`s of template literals.

Comment: Great idea, definitely gonna try it

Comment: @CertainPerformance would you care to share at least a little snippet of your parser? I'm having problems with variable names containing keywords. ex. "notlet anotletvar" is getting compiled to "let aletvar" instead of "let anotletvar", also as you said I'm still having problems with template literals and strings

Answer (score 1):

As CertainPerformance suggested I separated strings from the other code so that the parser can simply just replace stuff outside of strings and not worry about changing user-made strings. This is just my late night approach, I'm sure there's a better way to do it, but this will do just fine.

```
let code = fs.readFileSync('./code.js', {encoding:'utf8', flag:'r'}).split('\n')
let compiled = ''
code.forEach(line => {
    line.split(/(?=["'`])/).forEach(analLine => {
        if (!analLine.match(/^["'`].*/)) {
            compiled += analLine.replace('notlet', 'let')
                                .replace('notfor', 'for')
        } else {
            compiled += analLine
        }
    })
    compiled += '\n'
})
console.log(compiled)
eval(compiled)
```